# all prime elements of $ \Bbb{Z}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, p-adic-number-theory

> What are all prime elements of $\Bbb{Z}_p$ ?

$\Bbb{Z}_p$ is a local ring with unique maximal ideal $(p)$.
Prime element is generator of $(p)$, so $p$ and $-p$ are prime elements.
What about other prime elements ?

I couldn't come up with other prime elements of $\Bbb{Z}_p$. All prime elements are $±p$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Both answers and the question forget that (unless some terminology excludes it) $0$ is a prime element as well. So the full list is $0$, and all $up$ for units $u \in \mathbb Z_p$ (of which there are uncountably many).

Comment: You count $0$ as a prime ?  I think standard custom doesn't assume 0 to be a  prime element though $(0)$ be prime ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p$ is a prime element in a domain $A$, then all elements of the form $up$, with $u$ a unit in $A$, are prime as well and $(p)=(up)$.

If $A$ is local and its unique maximal ideal is principal generated by $p$, then the elements listed above are the only prime elements.

Indeed if $q$ is a prime element, we have $(q)\subseteq(p)$ and so $q=ap$ for some $a\in A$. Since $q$ is prime, we have either $a\in(q)$ or $p\in(q)$. In the latter case, $p=bq$ and we obtain $q=abq$, so $ab=1$ and $b$ is a unit. In the former case $a=cq$, so $1=cp$, which is a contradiction.

(By definition, prime elements are nonzero and noninvertible.)

Comment: How does $a=cq$ imply $q=acq$? Rather, we would get $q=cpq$ which via $1-cp$ being a unit forces $q=0$. The ideal $(0)$ is of course a prime ideal if $A$ is a domain, although by convention people seem to not call $0$ a prime element.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thanks, I fixed the argument.

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to finding all units of $\mathbb Z_p$, and since $\mathbb Z_p$ is local, $$\mathbb Z_p^{\times} = \cup_{x\in\{1, 2, \dots, p-1\}} x + p\mathbb Z_p.$$

In particular, $1+p+p^2+p^3+\cdots=\frac{1}{1-p}$ is a unit, and $(\frac{p}{1-p})=(p)$.

Comment: I think, for example, １+p is also a unit, so (p(1＋p))＝p, right ?

Comment: You mean, for ring R and p:prime element of R, all prime elements of R are obtained by the form  pu(u is a unit) ?

Comment: Yes, I mean, "...=$(p)$" the ideal, not $p$ itself. If $p$ is prime in a ring $R$, i.e. $(p)$ is a prime ideal, then $(up)=(p)$ iff $u$ is a unit. But other rings $R$ may have more than one nonzero prime ideal.

Comment: Sorry, my first comment's ・・・＝p was typo, ・・・＝(p).